# Github Actions: Run .sh without checking out whole project?

Tags: github, github-actions, git-checkout

Due to bandwidth limits, I'm trying to checkout a subfolder of my project to Github Actions and found this Action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout-files

New (broken) Script:

```
name: Create Build Target
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is creating ${{ github.ref_name }}
on: create
jobs:
  Create:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout to access bash script
        uses: Bhacaz/checkout-files@v2
        with:
          files: CICD

      - name: Create Buildtarget info on Unity Cloud Build
        env:
          api_key: ${{ secrets.api_key }}
          org_id: ${{ secrets.org_id }}
          project_id: ${{ secrets.project_id }}
          branch_name: ${{ github.ref_name }}
          credential_id: ${{ secrets.credential_id }}
        run: CICD/CreateBuildTarget.sh
```

I get an error in the Github Actions terminal when triggering the above .yaml file to check out a subdirectory instead of the whole project:

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/2ddc6165-7186-415a-8d87-bc4d746f659f.sh: line 1: CICD/CreateBuildTarget.sh: Permission denied
60
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.
```

I had this working before, and made sure the files had the correct permissions:

```
myUserName@myUserNames-MacBook-Pro cicd % ls -l
total 16
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myUserName  staff  2239 Feb  3 11:17 CreateBuildTarget.sh
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myUserName  staff   449 Feb  3 11:18 DeleteBuildTarget.sh
```

The only thing I changed was the checkout action.

Before (working):

```
      - name: Checkout to access bash script
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.6.0
```

After (not working):

```
      - name: Checkout to access bash script
        uses: Bhacaz/checkout-files@v2
        with:
          files: CICD
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? For now, I changed the script to trigger on pull request open/reopen, instead of create, but I still want to only check out a subdirectory instead of the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action you're using isn't setting the execute bits on the .sh files. It's relatively simple to add them manually after restoring the files, but you might want to fork the action and make it do the right thing.

[Try using a **Sparse Checkout** action](https://github.com/gogaille/sparse-checkout) instead, it would rely on Git to restore the files and has a lot more expected default behaviors built-in:

```
gogaille/sparse-checkout
```

Comment: Sure, but if the root cause, as I suggested, is the lack of executable bit on those script, you can use any GitHub Action you want: those files, once checked out one way or the other, won't execute.

Comment: He shows that full checkout works, so the problem isn't that the git repo is unaware if the execute bit. But the task he has chosen uses the GitHub API to fetch the file contents, but just writes it to a new file without looking at attributes at all. The action I mention above uses the git checkout features, thus would set the execute bit, but it also trims the set of files to download ti just the ones you need.

Comment: "thus would set the execute bit": interesting. I never knew a `git checkout` or `git restore` would do that. To me, if the file is versioned *without* the executable bit on one end, it will be checked out /restored *without* the executable bit on the other end, be its a manual checkout or a GitHub Action.

Comment: I tried this and it works: checks out only the files in the desired subfolder, and has the correct permissions. I did not fork the action though.

Answer (score 0):

While your files are executable locally (on your machine), they might not have been added to your Git repository with `+x` (the executable bit).

Which means, once the GitHub Action checks out your file (even limiting itself to one subfolder), said `sh` script files are not executable.

Try locally to do, using [`git add --chmod=+x`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---chmod-x):

```bash
cd /path/to/repository
cd CICD
git add --chmod=+x *.sh
git commit -m "Add executable bit in CICD folder"
git push
```

Then check if your GitHub Action has the same issue.